# Director of photography: як перекласти?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Неодноразово бачила, що хтось пише про себе: "director of photography". Як це прекладається українською? Фотограф, директор фотографії? Останній варіант дивний для мене, тому і питаю.

Comment: Треба розуміти, що тут _фотоґрафіја_ не скільки окрема річ, скільки окрема галузь — тут мистецтва, порівняйте з подібними словами: _ґеоґрафіја_, _кіноґрафіја_ тошчо.

Answer (score 1):

В англійській Вікіпедії:

> A **[cinematographer](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinematographer)** or **director of photography** (sometimes shortened to DP or DOP) is the chief over the camera and light crews working on a film, television production or other live action piece and is responsible for making artistic and technical decisions related to the image.

В українській Вікіпедії цій статті відповідає така:

> **[Оператор-постановник](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)** в художньому кінематографі — один з основних творців фільму, який безпосередньо працює над його образотворчим рішенням, керівник операторської групи.